# Got a stacktrace from Android Market that mentions a competitor's app

Tags: android, google-play, stack-trace

Does anyone know what this could possibly mean? Apparently someone else's app caused mine to crash?  And it happens to be an app that directly competes with mine:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create BackupAgent com.MY_COMPEITOR'S_APP.backup.BackupAgent: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateBackupAgent(ActivityThread.java:2905)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$4000(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2128)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at     android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(ActivityThread.java:529)
at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getClassLoader(ActivityThread.java:474)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateBackupAgent(ActivityThread.java:2873)
... 10 more
```

Comment: Where is the stack trace which shows YOUR app crashing?

Comment: not an expert, but i guess that the '10 more' can be helpful

Comment: It doesn't show my app crashing. This is from the Android Market Developer Console site. It's listed as a user-reported crash for my app, but this is all it tells me. I don't think I can expand the "10 more", or at least I don't know how. It's not a link.

Comment: Possibly what happened is that the other app crashed, and because of the similarity in name to my app, Android accidentally sent it to me instead of the other developer. By similar, I mean they both have a common word in the package name, but the two package names are certainly not the same.

Comment: @TenFour04: Yes, I think this looks very suspicious. Let's face it, stack trace info is very specific (including class names and line numbers). The fact your app isn't mentioned certainly suggests it didn't crash at all and there is some weird mix up.

Comment: I thought each app runs on its own VM and there is no way one application can hinder the functioning of the other! [Check](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) this out.

Comment: By chance do you have a intent that may be intercepted by the other app?

Comment: Do you make use of a backup agent at all? If so do you have a reference to the developer's  class in your AndroidManifest.xml that if the class didn't exist in your package, your application would crash? Like the result of a copy and paste from an example? Could you post your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Not using backup agent at all in my app. Don't have one referenced in my manifest. There's no reason why my competitor's package name would be anywhere in my code. I didn't even know what it was until I saw this.

Comment: Did you tried to contact Google/Android Team?

Comment: Trying installing your competitors app on your phone to see if you can reproduce the issue? Then you can get the full logcat.

Comment: That's a good idea... Maybe the other dev was not strict about filtering intents and we have a class with the same name. I'll try installing the other app. It has been a few months now, so it might have been fixed already.

Comment: I'm also getting similar crashes. And they come from my own custom reporting inside the app, so it's definitely not a bug in the android market reporting. Mine is something like "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create BackupAgent com.latedroid.juicedefender.Backup: java.lang.NullPointerException". The stacktrace doesn't show any part of my code, similar to what is shown here.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem... Did you find a solution please?

Answer (score 1):

TenFour I would bet since you are talking about a competing App that there must be some INtent Handling going on that led to this. Maybe the Competitor app was actually trying to do something at the same time your app was trying to do something and they clashed. Without knowing more it's hard to provide a more detailed answer